# group count of sum by column name

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I'm trying to get my data to be in a dataset with. I've tried using a group by on the column name, and a select group. I can't figure out the right syntax.

Desired Results:

```
 ColumnName |   Value
   a              2
   b              9
   c              12 
   d              15
   e              19
   f              14
   g              11
```

Here is what it currently returns

```
Column Name   a    b      c      d     e     f     g
Value         2    9      12     15    19    14    11
```

My query

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%is correct%' then 1 else 0 end) AS a,

SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%is incorrect%' then 1 else 0 end) AS b,

SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%not be reached%' then 1 else 0 end) AS         c,

SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%not attempted%' then 1 else 0 end) AS d,

SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%on site by EVA%' then 1 else 0 end) AS e,

SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%Initial followup call requested%' then 1 else 0 end) AS f,

SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%assigned by IVR%' then 1 else 0 end) AS VendorAssignedByIVR,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%Vendor refused%' then 1 else 0 end) AS VendorRefused,

SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%is too soon for multiple%' then 1 else 0 end) AS g,

SUM(CASE 
WHEN Note like '%is too soon for multiple%' then 1 else 0 end) AS     h

from fna..tblEventNotes n
```

Comment: What are the results you are trying to produce?

Comment: the top code, desired results

Comment: What's input? Share sample data...

Comment: At the first look it looks like you want to use pivot based on **Note** value, but the question does not contain enough information to post an answer.

Comment: What does `ConfirmedLocation`, `WrongLocation`, . . . have to do with "a", "b", "c" and so on?

Comment: I edited the example Gordon, does that make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a union. Do seperate selections on the every single column and combine them in a union. But if its about presenting it in a GUI its easier to use any form of template (depending on the component).

Comment: I normally create a temp datasource and fill it with a standard query. So in the needdatasource you just add a row for each column. You can do it with a for-loop on the columns.count taking the values from rows[0]. So keeping the query above and fill a datasource in the codebehind.